# Conditional rendering of screen with react navigation

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Recently I have been trying a navigation layout with `react-navigation`. I have 4 Tab which are nested inside a drawer navigation. I have 3 drawer label. I want to conditionally render the page of one tab, suppose **Home Tab** according to the active drawer label.
My codes are below:

> **Screens.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

export const LaptopHome = () => {
    return(
      <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#e3e3e3'}}>
        <Text>
          This is laptop Home Page.
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
}

export const CameraHome = () => {
  return(
    <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'skyBlue'}} >
      <Text>This is Camera Home Page</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

export const MobileHome = () => {
  return(
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <Text>This is a Mobile Home page</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

export const Orders = () => {
  return(
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <Text>Orders history details</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

export const Profile = () => {
  return(
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <Text>Profile details</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

export const Notification = () => {
  return(
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <Text>List of Notification</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

> **Routes.js**

```
import { StackNavigator, TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { FontAwesome } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { LaptopHome, CameraHome, MobileHome, Orders, Profile, Notification } from './Screens';

const HomeStack = StackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: LaptopHome //or CameraHome or MobileHome //Render according to active drawer label.
  }
});

const OrdersStack = StackNavigator({
  Order: {
    screen: Orders,
  }
});

const ProfileStack = StackNavigator({
  Profile: {
    screen: Profile,
  }
});

const NotificationStack = StackNavigator({
  Notification: {
    screen: Notification,
  }
});

const HomeTab = TabNavigator({
  HomeTab: {
    screen: HomeStack,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'Home',
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <FontAwesome name="home" size={24} color={tintColor} />,
    },
  },
  OrderTab: {
    screen: OrdersStack,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'Orders',
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <FontAwesome name="cart-arrow-down" size={24} color={tintColor} />
    },
  },
  ProfileTab: {
    screen: ProfileStack,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'Profile',
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <FontAwesome name="user" size={24} color={tintColor} />
    },
  },
  NotificationTab: {
    screen: NotificationStack,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'Notification',
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <FontAwesome name="bell" size={24} color={tintColor} />
    },
  }
}, {
initialRouteName: 'HomeTab',
tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
swipeEnabled: false,
tabBarOptions: {
  activeTintColor: '#4DD1A5',
  inactiveTintColor: '#AAADAC',
  upperCaseLabel: false,
  showIcon: true,
  style: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  labelStyle:{
    fontSize: 10,
    margin: 0,
  },
  indicatorStyle: {
    opacity: 0,
  },
},
});


export const AppNavigator = DrawerNavigator({
  Laptop: {
    screen: HomeTab,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: 'Laptop',
    }
  },
  Camera: {
    screen: HomeTab,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: 'Camera',
    }
  },
  Mobile: {
    screen: HomeTab,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: 'Mobile',
      drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
        <MaterialCommunityIcons name="table-large" size={24} color={tintColor} />
      ),
    }
  }
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Laptop',
  contentOptions: {
    activeTintColor: '#4DD1A5',
    inactiveTintColor: '#AAADAC',
    activeBackgroundColor: '#ffffff',
  }
});
```

> **App.js**

```
'use strict';

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {AppNavigator} from './Routes';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <AppNavigator />
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SimpleApp', () => App);
```

So, I want to conditionally render the HOME Tab according to the active drawer label.
I tried by accessing the state of the react-navigation, but it was of no help. Has anyone work around this or am I missing something.

Answer (score -1):

I know its been a while but just came cross with your question. I know you are using react-navigation but I can suggest you an alternative which is react-native-router-flux. It has other features as well as navigating. If you are interested in, you can reach more details by visiting https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux. But simply you may  follow the below steps to navigate your screens.

1- Add react-native-router-flux library to your project by installing it.

2- Create a router.js file which will host your major screen js classes. a simple example for that

```
import React from 'react';
import { Scene, Router } from 'react-native-router-flux';

const RouterComponent = () => {
return (
    <Router>
        {/*<Scene key="testScreen">
            <Scene key='testScene' component={RequestScreen} hideNavBar />
        </Scene>*/}
        <Scene key="loginNav">
            <Scene key="loginScreen" component={LoginForm} hideNavBar panHandlers={null} />
            <Scene direction="vertical" key="signupScreen" component={SignUp} />
    </Router>
);};export default RouterComponent;
```

As you see, you are creating a route, kind of a map that contains your screens to navigate between them.

3- Once you are done with configuration of routing, then you can go to any screen that you want to navigate from and import router-flux (export Actions from that library) and call the screen that you want navigate as below;

Actions.signupScreen();

thats all, you are good to go now. Hopefully, that helps you out. happy coding mate!

Comment: React-navigation has so many advantages over the react-native-router-flux. The react-native is changing drastically by time. Please be updated.

Comment: You did not have to down vote me but just could have warned to let me update my answer. What I was trying to do is providing an alternative that @hmachahary might find useful. What I said didn't underestimate the features of react-navigation and there is nothing here to down vote.